# Syntax Error for expected end of line bunt found unknown token writing Apple script for folder actions

Tags: macos, applescript

[image]

For the life of me I can't figure out what's causing this error. I have made sure to disable smart quotes, but keep getting the same error. The script itself is intended to automate handbrake video conversion, and admittedly I'm very new to playing with apple script but can't figure out what's causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full code in case it helps:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    with timeout of (720 * 60) seconds
        tell application "Finder"
            --Get all MOV files that have no label color yet, meaning it hasn't been processed 
            set allFiles to every file of entire contents of ("Macintosh HD:Users:MacMini:Downloads:Downloaded" as alias) whose (name extension is "mov" and label index is 0)

            --Repeat for all files in above folder
            repeat with i from 1 to number of items in allFiles
                set currentFile to (item i of allFiles)

                try
                    --Set to gray label to indicate processing
                    set label index of currentFile to 7

                    --Assemble original and new file paths
                    set origFilepath to quoted form of POSIX path of (currentFile as alias)
                    set newFilepath to (characters 1 thru -5 of origFilepath as string) &amp; "mp4'"

                    --Start the conversion
                    set shellCommand to "nice /Applications/HandBrakeCLI -i " &amp; origFilepath &amp; " -o " &amp; newFilepath &amp; " --preset=\"Fast 720p30\" --optimize ;"
                    tell current application
                        do shell script shellCommand
                    end tell

                    --Set the label to green in case file deletion fails
                    set label index of currentFile to 6

                    --Remove the old file
                    set shellCommand to "rm -f " &amp; origFilepath
                    tell current application
                        do shell script shellCommand
                    end tell
                on error errmsg
                    --Set the label to red to indicate failure
                    set label index of currentFile to 2
                end try
            end repeat
        end tell
    end timeout
end adding folder items to
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typical copy & paste error:

Replace **all** occurrences of `&amp;` with `&`